# How to get a Core Data Model Picture to fit to 1 page when printing?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, core-data

Ok, embarrassing, there must be an easy way - I have a Core Data model diagram that I want to print - printing is easy, but it pushes it over 4 pages which is difficult to carry around as a handy reference - how do I get it to shrink it onto 1 page?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

And if you're not on Xcode 4, you have to resort to n-up printing in preview and copy-pasting (the involving scissors kind) the pages together. The support for page setup was lost somewhere around Xcode 3.1.

Comment: For anyone else having this problem, please file a bug report to apple. You can reference the one I already submitted (9736616). The more people submit bugs, the more likely Apple is to fix it.

Answer (score 51):

I defined a 1m by 1m paper size, used it to create a PDF, cropped and then printed it:

- Go to "File"->"Page Setup…"
- Go to "Paper Size"->"Manage Custom Sizes…"
- Define a new paper size with 1000x1000 mm and no borders
- Go to "File"->"Print…"
- Choose "PDF"->"Open PDF in Preview"
- Go to "Tools"->"Rectangular Selection", select the area to crop
- Do "Tools"->"Crop"
- Go to "File"->"Print…", print

Sounds complicated, but works. Instead of cropping, you could use the scale factor in the Preview print dialog.

Comment: Excellent ! This is the answer which should be accepted ! This seems the only way to have everything on one single page. Thank you !

Comment: This is very useful. I named the new paper size Metre Squared. On the next time I used it Metre Squared was greyed out, but by just opening the Manage Custom Sizes dialog I was able to select it.

Comment: Save my day. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem described above, where the zoom didn't really seem to work well much below about 70-80%.  I found that if (in XCode 4) you go to File->Page Setup, then choose a different size of paper that the model will fit onto 1 page (I chose A3).  Then go to File->Print but instead of printing the document, choose "Save PDF".  Then view the resulting PDF file using Preview, and print from there: Preview will allow you to scale the image in the Print dialog so that it fits on whatever size paper your printer supports.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this in XCode 4 - as mentioned, there is a "Page Setup" with Zoom option - however it seems to be limited - any zoom level below 70% seems to produce inconsistent results: either it thinks that it now fits on a single page, but parts are cut off, or it doesn't actually decrease the zoom an further as you request smaller percentages....

Answer (score 0):

It's a little counter-intuitive, but in XCode (4) whilst viewing your data model go to `File->Page Setup`, which will let you adjust the zoom level.

You can then go to print and check the zoom level is high enough to fit your diagram onto a single sheet.