# Change zoom on Xcode's core data graph view?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, core-data

Is there a way to zoom out or zoom in when looking at a core data model's graph view in Xcode 5.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not.but you can "fold in" your entities so that they do not show all attributes. This might help you.

Comment: Thanks to you... no thanks to Apple.  I suppose interface builder zoom stinks, too.

Comment: Yes IB zoom is also limited: you can only edit view(controller)s when zommed in, nit when zommed out. Also, there is a fixed zoomed-in and zoomed-out percentage.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one workaround:

You could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13792875/427083) to generate a PDF file via print and then use Preview to zoom in and out.