# How to take screenshot of complete scrolled file

Tags: core-data, scroll, screenshot, document, webpage-screenshot

How to take screenshot of complete scrolled file of core data from x-code project.

Here my file core data is very huge I want to take screenshoot of it **MyProject.xcdatamodeld**. Since planning for documentation, I need the coredata diagram style screen.  Unable to take from preview. 
 Is there any tool or software that can take screen shot from scrolled content ?

In other word how to take screen shot from mouse pointer capture till end scrolling content.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by *unable to take from preview*.  But the only way to do this is to File > Print to .pdf.  Read the various answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745099/how-to-get-a-core-data-model-picture-to-fit-to-1-page-when-printing).

Comment: Preview will take window frame screen capture.  What if I have context still scrollabl,  here preview fails for my requirement.

Comment: @kiran: "Printing" the pdf in Preview will print all content.  If you actually print, it will print to multiple pieces of paper, or one piece if you have a huge printer.  If instead you save to pdf, you can get multiple pages, or one huge page.  This is explained in the last answer of the question I linked to.

Comment: Now I got it, it’s really work after long time using print pdf.   